# Implementing Floyd-Warshall algorithm for a list of vertices

Tags: java, graph

im trying to return transitive closure from the list of vertices but how can i use floyd warshall algorithm to do so? All the examples in the Internet are given in 2D arrays but can it be also used for a list? Example G = ABCD --> G+ = AB AC AD BC BD CD, where G is list of vertices and G+ is transitive closure.

My implementation(the wrong way):

```
 public Graph transitiveClosure(LinkedList<Vertex> v)
  {

      String graaf = "";      
      Edge e;
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(graaf);

      Iterator<Vertex> i = v.iterator();
      Vertex tmp;
      for(Vertex vertex : v)
      {
         System.out.print(vertex);
      }

         while(i.hasNext()) {         
        int next = (v.size() + 1) - v.size();                                        
         tmp =(Vertex) i.next();

         if(tmp == v.getFirst()) 
        tmp = (Vertex)i.next();
        e = new Edge(v.getFirst().toString() + tmp);                        
        sb.append(e); 

         if(tmp == v.get(next)) 
         next++;
         e = new Edge(v.get(next).toString() + tmp);
         sb.append(e);


    }

      System.out.println();

      return new Graph(sb.toString());
      }              
}
```

Comment: pls explain your example. do you want merely all pairs (i,j) where indicies i<j within the v list?

Comment: Yes i need all pairs

Answer (score 1):

since you want all pairs (i,j) where i and j are indicies with i lower than j, i dont quite understand why you want Floyd-Warshall here.

```
int size = v.size();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(graaf);
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
   for (int j=i+1;j<size;j++) {
      sp.append(v.get(i)+v.get(j)+" ");
   }
}
```